# Remote debug WebLogic cluster

Tags: remote-debugging, weblogic-10.x

I need to remotely debug a Java EE application running on a WebLogic 10.3.5 cluster.  It is important that I debug it whilst clustered, not running on a single box.

I have read docs that state you can either modify the Java Options in the start script or the debug flag in the domain config, however what I do not understand is how you know which server to connect to when clustered.

My cluster is configured for round robin load balancing so I have no way of knowing which server to connect my debugger to.

Is it possible to connect the remote debugger to the cluster rather than a single server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem there's no domain or cluster level connection available.  One must open a new debugger connection to each server.

It just wasn't obvious in my IDE that clicking debug more than once would open multiple debugger connections.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this,

1. Create Debug configuration with Host and Port number of the Admin Server which manages the cluster servers.
2. Try debug on admin server.